# How to delete values from one pandas series that are common to another?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series, drop

So I have a specific problem that needs to be solved. I need to DELETE elements present in one pandas series (ser1) that are common to another pandas series (ser2).

I have tried a bunch of things that do not work and the closest thing I was able to find was with arrays using np.intersect1d() function. This works to find common values, but when I try to drop indexes that are equal to these values, i get a bunch of mistakes.

I've tried a bunch of other things that did not really work and have been at it for 3 hours now so about to give up.

here are the two series:

```
ser1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
ser2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

The result should be:

```
print(ser1)
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

I am sure there is a simple solution.

Comment: look at `Series.isin()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A numpy alternative, [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ser1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
ser2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

res = ser1[~np.isin(ser1, ser2)]
print(res)
```

**Micro-Benchmark**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ser1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5] * 100)
ser2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7, 8] * 10)
%timeit res = ser1[~np.isin(ser1, ser2)]
136 µs ± 2.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit res = ser1[~ser1.isin(ser2)]
209 µs ± 1.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit pd.Index(ser1).difference(ser2).to_series()
277 µs ± 1.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I think you should throw in python's set here as well

Comment: @sammywemmy Not sure how use set here, you mean convert to set and back to series?

Comment: ``set(ser1).difference(ser2)`` ... danger with set though is that it is unordered

Comment: Works, thanks for your time!

Comment: @sammywemmy Set is really fast, but is not ordered. For the same values it gives 29us

Answer (score 7):

Use [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
>>> ser1[~ser1.isin(ser2)]
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

The numpy version is [`.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) (and not `.intersect1d`)

```
>>> np.setdiff1d(ser1, ser2)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use set notation - I am not sure of the speed though, compared to isin:

```py
pd.Index(ser1).difference(ser2).to_series()
Out[35]: 
1    1
2    2
3    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This works well thank you, is there a reason as to why the index of the new series doesn't start at 0 though?

Comment: ahhh ... so the index is repeated, both as an index, and as a Series. within the `to_series` method, you can manually pass in the new index. or just reset_index

Comment: To reset index I used: ser1 = `(pd.Index(ser1).difference(ser2).to_series())
ser1 = ser1.reset_index()
print(ser1)` and it gave me this as an answer : `Name: alphabets, dtype: object
   index  0
0      1  1
1      2  2
2      3  3`

Comment: use ``reset_index(drop=True)``

Comment: Works, thank you for your answer, much appreciated!